# How I can connect these two points?

Tags: edges

[image: How I can connect this 2 points with straight line (verticle)? I can't press For J]

How I can connect this 2 points with straight line (verticle)? I can't press <kbd>F</kbd>or <kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: if they are part of 2 different objects you can't fill between these 2 vertices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those two points are from two different objects, you can't connect them without combine the objects by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, then you can use <kbd>F</kbd>.
If you don't want to combine the objects, you can try doing it using curve,but it might look weird.

Comment: thanks, the main problem was in unjoining 2 objects, when i solved it next steps was pretty easy, ty for help!!!